# Limit Voice Over to active view controller

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

I have an app with the classic "hamburger menu" to open settings. When pressed in slides in from the left covering most of the screen. How ever, when Voice over is activated and you swipe right when the last element is active, it activates the first element in the hidden view controller. I guess this kind of makes sense for a split view controller, but not in this case.

Is it possible to tell Voice Over only to "see" elements in the active view controller?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to set `accessibilityElementsHidden` for hamburger menu view (when it hides set it to `true`, when it's being shown set to `false`)?

Answer (score 3):

You want your hamburger menu to behave as a modal, over the current context. You would acheive that as such:

```
menuViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of above answers led me to the good solution. The biggest problem was to find the container view for my settings view. When I did, I used `accessibilityViewIsModal = true` when the hamburger button was pressed and `accessibilityViewIsModal = false` when it was closed.

`accessibilityElementshidden` on the main content container view also worked, but I feel it makes more sense to mark the settings view as modal.

Comment: Changes that come as a result of manipulating accessibility APIs are not ideal, in this case. The view should be modal for everyone, not just AT users.